# Custom field type editable in Excel mode?

Tags: custom-field-types

I have written a custom field type with this definition (to be used in SP2010):

```
<FieldTypes>
  <FieldType>
    <Field Name="TypeName">MyField</Field>
    <Field Name="ParentType">Number</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeDisplayName">My Field</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeShortDescription">My field description</Field>
    <Field Name="AllowBaseTypeRendering">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="UserCreatable">FALSE</Field>
    <Field Name="FieldTypeClass">$SharePoint.Type.3e27f5e8-348d-40c6-afcc-87306b2bb3ac.AssemblyQualifiedName$</Field>
    <Field Name="Sortable">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="Filterable">TRUE</Field>
  </FieldType>
</FieldTypes>
```

Basically, this custom field extend the native SPFieldNumber to provide a custom UI:

```
[Guid("3E27F5E8-348D-40C6-AFCC-87306B2BB3AC")]
public class MyField: SPFieldNumber
{
    public MyField(SPFieldCollection fields, string fieldName)
        : base(fields, fieldName)
    {
    }

    public MyField(SPFieldCollection fields, string typeName, string displayName)
        : base(fields, typeName, displayName)
    {
    }

    public override Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseFieldControl FieldRenderingControl
    {
        get
        {
            return new MyFieldControl
            {
                FieldName = this.InternalName,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The custom field works fine in the standard `newform.aspx` and `editform.aspx`. However, when I create a datasheet view, the field is read only:

[image]

What have I to do to make the field editable in the datasheet view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is SharePoint behavior. Custom fields are not editable in datasheet view.

Comment: I'm still eager to find some hack to override this issue (but I'm realistic, it will probably won't be possible).

Comment: I would love to see if there is any hack. A user had requested me once to provide edit functionality to my custom field control "Autocomplete Lookup Field" https://autocompletelookup.codeplex.com/discussions/361944

Comment: Is there any Microsoft link reference for this? I would appreciate if you can provide me such link. It will be very helpful then. Thanks in advance.